# why is it showing "type object 'CourseInstructor' has no attribute 'objects' "

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

i'm using class based views because classes can't be defined in function based views. i have two models (Course, CourseInstructor) when i created the first model and checked it there was no such error but when i created the second model, it displayed that error.

```
-- models.py --
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    courseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    courseName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    maxNumbOfStudents = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.courseName, self.courseNumber, self.maxNumbOfStudents

class CourseInstructor(models.Model):
    courseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    instructorNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "CourseInstructor"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.instructorNumber + " - " + self.courseNumber

-- views.py --
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render
from django.views import View
from .models import Course, CourseInstructor

class Course(View):
    def get(self, request):
        courses = Course.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'examscheduling.html', {'courses': courses})

class CourseInstructor(View):
    def get(self, request):
        coursesInstructor = CourseInstructor.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'examscheduling.html', {'coursesInstructor': coursesInstructor})
```

Comment: you are new to site, please paste your traceback here, we can understand the message of the error and guide you.

Comment: You should not name your class based views exactly the same thing as your models. Rename them to `CourseView` and `CourseInstructorView`

Comment: what is traceback @ytsejam ?

Comment: @tim-mccurrach now there is no error but it is not showing the second table.

Comment: @ZainSadaqat What do you mean by not showing the second table. Please add the template to your question (just the relevant part of it, not the whole thing). It's difficult to help without that. It would probably be useful to see the models as well.

Comment: @tim-mccurrach i added the models.py code. kindly check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your both models like this

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):

    """your other fields"""
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: kindly check if i'v written correctly and how can i use it?

class CourseInstructor(models.Model):
    courseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    instructorNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = models.Manager()

Comment: Yes, it is correct. It shouldn't give error anymore when you write CourseInstructor.objects.all(). Make sure you add this in your all models to have objects attribute. Do you still get an error?

Comment: it doesn't show any error but second table's values are not being displayed in html file. i think we can't use two class based views in single file or something else

Comment: Share your html file

Comment: <table>
            <tr>
    <th>Course No.</th>
    <th>Course Name</th>
    <th>Max No. Students</th>
        </tr>
    {% for course in courses %}
        <tr>
    <td>{{ course.courseNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ course.courseName }}</td>
    <td>{{ course.maxNumbOfStudents }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
       <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Course No.</th>
    <th>Instructor No.</th>
    </tr>

    {% for ci in coursesInstructor %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ ci.courseNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ ci.instructorNumber }}</td>
  </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

Comment: Delete from comment and add in your question to let other people see.